# eclipse: turning folder hierarchy into a package

Tags: eclipse, package, package-explorer

I have the following folder hierarchy in eclipse. I would like to
turn the folder hierarchy com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android
into a package (the folder icon with the gift box inside it for the src folder,
and right below it a single folder with a gift box icon rather than many standard
folders one inside the other). How can I achieve this?

[image]

In the above picture I want the package directory structure to look like the
one above with a single package icon: com.google.package.gms.auth.sample.helloauth

Thanks.

Comment: I think only package presentation can be hierarchical or flat, might not in folder...

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please explain. I do not understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I was running the code I was getting a runtime error whereby the class
with the name specified in AndroidManifest.xml was not being found. I fixed
the problem by right-clicking on my project and creating a
New -> Package with source folder named "src".

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

OPENING THE SOURCE TOOL:
In eclipse, right click on your project. From the context menu, hover over 'Build Path.' Once the submenu displays, navigate to 'Configure Build Path.' The resulting display will be a large overlay-type menu with multiple tabs inside. The first of these is labeled 'Source.' This is where folders are changed to Source folders.

ADDING SOURCES:
If you want your source to be a nested set, such as `src/main/java`, you first need to remove any potentially nested sources (e.g. `src` or `src/main`) from the current list. Next, click the 'add' button. From the hierarchical list of folders, select the first and last folders in your nested set (for `src/main/java`, you will check the `src` and `java` folders.)

REMOVING SOURCES (KEEPING FOLDERS):
Alternatively, highlighting a source folder and clicking 'remove' will not delete the folder, but will instead remove it from the build path. From there, It is easy enough just to add it back to the build path. In fact, it will sometimes stay in the explorer as a regular folder.

It may take a bit of experimenting to get the hang of, but I assure you that all is possible structure-wise from in this box, as I just restructured a Spring Boot Project from here.

Answer (score 0):

If your folder is turning into package format. then do below:

right click on your package -> Build Path -> exclude
[image]

This will convert package into simple folder/directory format.